# andengine throw a ball with a force and at a particular angle

Tags: android, andengine, angle, throw

In AndEngine game, I want to throw a ball physics body. The user sets its angle and force and throws it. Its scenario is same as we can see in Angry Birds. I have calculated both the force and angle but am confused how to apply both simultaneously on ball means the ball should be thrown at calculated angle but with particular force. Can anybody guide me to the right direction?

Here is my code snippet:

```
@Override
public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent event,ITouchArea pTouchArea, float x, float y) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(event.isActionDown()) {
        ......
    }
    else if(event.isActionMove()) {
        ......
    }
    else if(event.isActionCancel() || event.isActionOutside() || event.isActionUp()) {
        .....
        launchHero(hero, string1.getX1()/PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT, string1.getY1()/PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT, x/PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT, y/PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT);
}

public void launchHero(Hero hero, float originX, float originY, float fingerX, float fingerY) {
    Vector2 shoot = new Vector2((originX - fingerX), -(originY - fingerY));
    shoot = shoot.nor().mul(10);

    hero.getBody().setLinearVelocity(shoot);

}
    }

    return false;

}
```

I have added negative to (originY - fingerY) because if I don't do this, the ball first goes down then after colliding with base, it goes up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very simple, use `Body.setLinearVelocity(Vector2 pVector)`. Both direction and force are determined by the vector's parameters. Here's a sample code:

```
Vector2 shoot = new Vector2((originX - fingerX), (originY - fingerY));
body.setLinearVelocity(shoot);
```

This will shoot the body in the direction made by the finger and place of origin, or, in the case of Angry Birds, the finger and the sling.

If you want to make the force constant and multiply it by some number, you can do this before shooting:

```
shoot = shoot.nor().mul(multiplier);
```

Comment: I have tried this. But the ball just go upward even if user wants it to go downward.

Comment: Please give me a sample of what values you feed to originX, originY, fingerX, fingerY. I use this code and it works for me.

Comment: originX=4.78125, originY=9.4375, fingerX=0.625, fingerY=0.625

Comment: The ball is attached to a string like line and user stretches the string and release it to throw the ball. I have to launch a ball according to stretch of string and angle. User can drag it to any direction.

Comment: It seems you assign the values from the TouchEvent to the wrong variables, fingerX/Y should change and originX/Y should stay the same.

Comment: You are getting the values in a very strange way. Why do you get the values from onAreaTouched? This method is more for handling the events when user touches a Sprite. Why don't you override onSceneTouchEvent instead? Then you can simply check for 'pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP' and get the values from pSceneTouchEvent.getX() and getY(). I made a picture describing the situation with both points, the vector and axes of the scene. Since my code works, you are getting the WRONG VALUES. You need to look around and make sure you get the right ones. See http://bit.ly/SzOY2w

Comment: Yes. I have identified one logical mistake by reading your comment i.e. I am getting x,y from onAreaTouched which are relative from within the area touched. I think if I do as you said in onSceneTouchEvent, it will solve my problem. But I cannot do this in onSceneTouchEvent because user has to drag the ball to set angle. I am using onSceneTouchEvent to move scene to and fro, same as in angry birds. So what should I do in this case? Thanks for such a time.

Comment: Thanks I solved it as you mentioned jusy be passing x and y positions of ball body to launchHero as x and y. Its working fine. Thank you so much for giving me such a great time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
body.applyLinearImpulse(Vector2 impulse, Vector2 point)
```

I prefer this function on `setLinearVelocity` because it gives more possibilities. To use this function you need to give the impulse in both coordinates and the body's point where to apply it.